# Nested class - isn't this an incomplete type

Tags: c#, .net, internals

**Sample code:**

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    private NestedClass nestedClass = new NestedClass();

    public class NestedClass : SimpleClass          
    {

    }
}

// when instantiating in say.. main()
SimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass();
```

I come from C++ background, and so I am having difficulty wrapping my head around what is going on here. Specifically how can we instantiate `NestedClass` inside `SimpleClass`. Since ideally compiler will need full layout of `SimpleClass` to be able to instantiate `NestedClass`, which in turn needs `SimpleClass`. Its kinda recursive in nature.

And this is what happens when we run this code. We get a `StackOverflow` :) exception!

In C++ world, compiler would cry "`incomplete type`" in such cases.

**So the crux of my question is:**

1. What's going on here, how does compiler layout this class (I know its implementation detail, but without complete type how can we instantiate an object?)
2. Is this runtime exception intentional, or is it something that should be a compile time error?

Comment: Imagine that `SimpleClass` contains a pointer `NestedClass *nestedClass` (incomplete type problem could be worked out in C++ by using forward declaration and moving stuff around)

Comment: I've never used c++ (can't even read it), and have been working in .net for over a decade now. Never crossed my mind to even try to write such a code. It seems so wrong to me that I can't even think of a valid use-case of the top of my head (though there probably are some of them out there).

Comment: @ZoharPeled a related use case is when using NullObject pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern#C#  though it uses static field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that it's a nested class is irrelevant here. The fact that it's a *derived* class is for more important. Aside from details around generics and access (e.g. nested classes having access to private members of the containing class) there's relatively little difference between an nested class and a non-nested class.

So let's show that:

```
class BaseClass
{
    DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

This still compiles, and still fails with a `StackOverflowException` if you try to create an instance of `BaseClass` (or `DerivedClass`).

The *layout* is fine: `BaseClass` has a single field, which is a reference to a `DerivedClass`. There's no issue in terms of knowing "how big" either `BaseClass` or `DerivedClass` are - and indeed without the initialization aspect, this would be absolutely fine. What's important here is that `DerivedClass` is a reference type, so the value of the `derived` field is *just* a reference.

There are no C# language rules being broken here, and designing a language rule that would prohibit this without prohibiting valid use cases would be really hard.

The recursion here really isn't that different to what you can do with a single class:

```
class BaseClass
{
    BaseClass other = new BaseClass();
}
```

Again, it's perfectly valid code, but causes a stack overflow.

---

The problem I *suspect* you're thinking of is easily demonstrated with structs, although without inheritance involved:

```
struct Tweedledum
{
    Tweedledee dee;
}

struct Tweedledee
{
    Tweedledum dum;
}
```

This *does* fail, because there's no appropriate layout: a `Tweedledum` value contains a `Tweedledee` value directly, and vice versa. Not a reference: the actual value.

The error here is:

```
error CS0523: Struct member 'Tweedledum.dee' of type 'Tweedledee' causes a cycle in the struct layout
error CS0523: Struct member 'Tweedledee.dum' of type 'Tweedledum' causes a cycle in the struct layout
```

Comment: This makes sense! For folks from C/C++ background reading this, in simple terms the _nestedClass_ is more like a _*p_nestedClass_ and thus compiler only need to allocate the architecture Word Size for it. And so the defined class is a complete type!